# Simple, stable $n$-body orbits in the plane with some fixed bodies allowed

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, big-list

I'm working on a visual simulator for the $n$-body problem in the plane ([here](http://reallyeli.com/pages/planets.html)). The goal is to show how complex behavior can arise from the simple inverse-square law of gravity.

To that end, I want to showcase cool stable orbits. I have three of them already:

- moving planet around fixed star
- moving stars orbiting each other
- moving planet on a straight line between two starts

What other simple orbits are there? I'm allowing myself to fix some bodies in place, in order to emulate the real-world situation where one body is much more massive than another.

All answers are appreciated, but I'd especially appreciate pictures and information on how to construct the orbits (initial velocities and positions).

Comment: Not sure what the protocol is on questions like this, as there is no single "answer". I'd be fine with making it community wiki, if that's appropriate, but I don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [Lagrange point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point) relative to the positions of two massive objects is a third point with the property that a small object moving under the gravitational influence of the others remains in relative equilibrium.  The following image (taken from Wikipedia and licensed under CC) shows the five Lagrange points in a Sun-Earth like system, together with contours of the associated potential:

[image]

As the image indicates, there are five Lagrange points labeled $L_1$ through $L_5$. The first three are unstable while the last two are generally stable. Thus, we can see three bodies moving under gravity that maintain their relative positions on a triangle. The size of that triangle can change, but not it's shape. The degree of that stability depends on the relative masses, however.

One specific set of initial conditions in the plane with a gravitational constant of $G=1$ illustrating this type of orbit is given by:

- Body 1:

  - Mass: 4
  - Position: $(0,0)$
  - Velocity: $(0,-1/\sqrt{2})$
- Body 2:

  - Mass: 4
  - Position: $(1,0)$
  - Velocity: $(0,1/\sqrt{2})$
- Body 3:

  - Mass: 0.0001
  - Position: $(1/2,\sqrt{3}/2)$
  - Velocity: $(-\sqrt{3/2},0)$

The evolution of this configuration looks like so:

[image]

I think this system would make a great illustration of chaos because the masses have been chosen so that we don't have to deviate very much before things go haywire.  If we move the position of the small object just slightly to the left, from $x=0.5$ to $x=0.48$, we obtain the following evolution:

[image]

Another very cool point to make in a presentation concerning Lagrange points is that they can be observed in nature. There is, supposedly, a huge amount of space debris located at the Sun/Jupyter $L_4$ and $L_5$ points.

---

A second type of fun illustration is simply animation from a random initial configuration.  That it, pick $n$ initial masses and place them at $n$ initial locations. One could also pick $n$ initial velocities, though that get's trickier, since the overall picture has non-trivial momentum.

Here, for example, is the evolution of 5 random point masses at 5 random locations:

[image]

Comment: You are using monochrome equilateral triangles to represent directions! Are you completely insane?! (But I love that last graphic.)

Comment: @TonyK Thanks, I think. :) I do like that last graphic too. I don't really understand your first sentence, though. In the stable illustration, the three objects do indeed maintain a configuration where they lie at the vertices of an equilateral triangle. I'm not sure what monochrome means and I don't know what you mean by by "represent direction"?

Comment: Those little blue and red triangles in your first graphic $-$ each of them is supposed to be pointing in a particular direction, right? But an equilateral triangle points in three directions at once...

Comment: @Tonyk Ah - I see. That's not my graphic. I lifted it from Wikipedia and mentioned that in the answer. But, yeah, you're right; they do appear to be representing directions of stable and unstable manifolds or some such. I did produce the animations, though.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: You are an absolute hero! This is beautiful. How did you make the gifs?

Comment: @EliRose Thanks! Maybe, I'll get 166 upvotes. :) I used Mathematica to make the animated GIFs. I'd be happy to share the code but, of course, you might or might not have easy access. My impression is that one doesn't need a fancy ODE integrator to generate these things, though.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Relatedly -- so I'm trying to implement this now, and need to space them farther apart (say, 1 $\mapsto$ 50) in order to see the action.  I thought I should simply multiply position and velocity by $50$, since mass is independent, but that's not working at all -- they fly apart instantly. Does the inverse-squaredness of gravity mean I should multiply the masses by $50^2$?

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Another culprit could be that my $\Delta t$ for the solver is too big.

Comment: @EliRose If you increase your distances, you'll need to *divide* your velocities by that same amount to preserve the angular momentum in the system. The resulting ellipses will have a larger eccentricity, however. Another approach is to: magnify the distances by a common factor, multiply your gravitational constant $G$ by the same factor, leave the velocities the same, and run your animation longer.

Comment: @EliRose Incidentally, I just wrote a Python implementation of this as well and used it to generate the random evolution that I just posted.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Good idea -- maybe starting the viewer off with a random configuration will make the stable configurations more beautiful/surprising. So if I increase the distances by a factor of $50$, wouldn't multiplying all the masses by $50$ amount to the same thing as multiplying $G$ by the same factor?

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Also, why is the following reasoning wrong: multiplying the distances by $a$ corresponds to describing the same physical situation in different units, so I multiply everything that has units of length by $a$, right? That would be velocity and position. Does the answer have to do with the units of G?

Comment: @EliRose I think that the main issue is that the forces and, therefore, the accelerations scale in a completely different way.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Not sure I quite understand -- if I make the substitution $1 \text{inch} \mapsto 2.54 \text{cm}$ then shouldn't I be observing the same system? Even at the given values, your example isn't stable in my simulation, so I think the simulation may not be precise enough.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Update: my simulation is still too rough for your example, but I used your advice to make something else work better! Thank you!

Comment: @EliRose Awesome! I notice on your StackOverflow info page that you've got some Python tags. It seems that SciPy's `odeint` command works swell for this.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can witness complex (or chaotic) behavior via a simulation with some of the bodies fixed, it usually pays to run a complete numeric solution to the general problem, since any non-fixed bodies can always run chaotically fairly easily.

If, on the other hand, you wish to fix some of the bodies, you can tweak the general solution by giving them large masses and 0 velocities relative to the smaller ones in the simulation.

The main thing the engine for the solution does is simply calculate discrete updates for (all bodies):

1) Acceleration (from Newton)

2) Velocity

3) Position

Such an engine is best understood by example, so if you have access to Maple, I am including a .pdf with some code on it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzr3EyK8arkOcXo0RzRMTEVOX0k/view?usp=sharing).

Even if you don't have Maple, you should be able to pick the code apart and see how it calculates the following 3 animations, which are run by changing N only (N=4, N=3 and N=2).

Chaotic behavior can then be witnessed fairly easily, by fiddling with the initial velocities, which may produce among other things, body crashes and/or escapes.

In the animations below, the initial velocities were tweaked so that the system would be stable, at least for the duration of the animation.

[image]

[image]

[image]