# An explanation for mathematicians of the three-body problem using a simple example, and the moons of Saturn

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I am curious to know a simple example that provide me evidence that there are no solution (maybe chaotic) for the so-called three-body problem, and an explanation from an informative point of view of what means a phrase that I've read in Wikipedia's article dedicated to the Moons of Saturn.

I know from an informative point of view that there is an unsolved problem in physics concerning the motion in a gravitational field of more of two bodies, is the so-called three-body problem, see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem). On the other hand Wikipedia's article dedicated to the [Moons of Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Saturn) tell us in the first paragraph that Saturn has *62 moons with confirmed orbits*.

> **Question.** A) Can you answer as a reference request or with yourself didactic example (I would like to know a simple example, explained from an informative point of view for mathematicians) about an example of motion of three or more bodies where is evidenced that there is no solution, or well it is chaotic?
>
> B) What is the meaning of a *confirmed orbit* in the quote that I've cited in my second paragraph? It means that with numerical analysis or different evidence (measurement of periods or photographs of such moons) that physics known that a moon has a confirmed orbit or what is my misunderstanding? **Many thanks.**

I am asking B) because I don't know if the orbits of such moons are solutions of an equation or these are determined from a different way.

Comment: My limited understanding is that in the case of the Saturnian system of moons (or Jovian, or...) the orbits are essentially those of a two-body system (=Saturn + a single moon). The point is that the existing moons have such feeble effects on each other, that those can be handled as minor perturbations to the two-body system orbit. In other words, Saturn is the boss, and the moons just follow the lead. To see chaotic behavior you need 3 bodies of comparable masses. Code/run simulations to see that. The caveat there is that it is not clear how to tell the difference...

Comment: (cont'd) between truly chaotic behavior and artefacts produced by approximations you do to make the simulation. I'm afraid I'm not an expert on how to code that well.

Comment: Now I understand the quote of Wikipedia, many thanks @JyrkiLahtonen feel free to add your comment as an answer for B)

Comment: Anyway, due to the age of the Solar system we can relatively safely assume that moons indulging in chaotic behavior have escaped, impacted on Saturn, ... whatnot... ages ago.

Comment: I don't think I'm worthy to **answer** this. I was once told here that to make a simulation observing conservation laws (that my simplistic incremental simulations violated when I ran them to the amusement of myself and my son) you would need to use so called *symplectic integrators* whatever they may be.

Comment: It's your decision @JyrkiLahtonen . Now if the moons fall for lack of your explanation it will be your responsibility.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1392051/11619), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1613765/11619) for something better than what I can offer.

Comment: Many thanks @JyrkiLahtonen and my previous comment was a joke :)

Comment: That is how I see it. Solution may exist, it is, however, impossible to obtain it in closed form. That is just a mathematical fact: "3 body problem is not an integrable dynamical system". There are simply not enough integrals of motion to reduce it to quadratures.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution @KirylPesotski and attention, if you want to expand your commment as an answer, adding details (definitions or about your reasoning or other aspects). I am looking for an answer/feedback for A) and B). The moderator in previous comment added some remarkable posts from this site.

Comment: @user243301 It is hard for me to elaborate on the existence of the solutions, as I'm not a specialist in those things and my theoretical mechanics course was quite long ago. However, I can prove you the non-integrability.

Comment: @user243301 Remark: There of course exist a 3 body problem which has an exact solution. This is a problem of 3 bodies interacting via the harmonic potential $V(\vec{x}_{1}, \vec{x}_{2})=-\gamma(\vec{x}_{1}-\vec{x}_{2})^{2}$. It this problem the solutions not only exist, but one also can obtain them in the closed form.

Comment: Many thanks any case @KirylPesotski